# Detecting Mouse Movement Without JQuery

Tags: javascript, mouse

I'm looking for a small piece of javascript that will check for mouse movement and in the event it does execute a function. I'm looking to do this **without jquery** and preferably compatible with most modern browsers. I have this small script which detects when the mouse isn't moving:

```
<script>
document.onmousemove = (function() {
  var onmousestop = function() {
    /* do stuff */
  }, thread;

  return function() {
    clearTimeout(thread);
    thread = setTimeout(onmousestop, 500);
  };
})();
</script>
```

I'm hoping things can be edited into firing the do stuff when the mouse is moved for the first time after loading the script? Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem with [Amit's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13206146/27862) is that it removes any existing mousemove listeners. Also, it doesn't clean up when the mouse is first moved, and thus creates unnecessary overhead.

This is the clean way of doing it:

```
var myListener = function () {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', myListener, false);
    // do stuff
};

document.addEventListener('mousemove', myListener, false);
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/JQBmA/

If you need to support older IEs, you can use this:

```
var addListener, removeListener;
if (document.addEventListener) {
    addListener = function (el, evt, f) { return el.addEventListener(evt, f, false); };
    removeListener = function (el, evt, f) { return el.removeEventListener(evt, f, false); };
} else {
    addListener = function (el, evt, f) { return el.attachEvent('on' + evt, f); };
    removeListener = function (el, evt, f) { return el.detachEvent('on' + evt, f); };
}

var myListener = function () {
    removeListener(document, 'mousemove', myListener);
    // do stuff
};

addListener(document, 'mousemove', myListener);
```

Comment: "If you need to support older IEs..." - I wish it wasn't the case :( I hate IE so bad

Comment: which version of IE needs the latter here do you know?

Comment: its jquery not the solution asked by user

Answer (score 2):

```
(function(){
   var moved = false
   window.onmousemove = function(e){
      if(!moved){
          moved = true;
          // do what you want after mousemove, here
      }
   }
})()
```

Comment: Thanks, works very well. One thing to note for IE, onmousemove doesn't work when applied to the window object so use document.onmousemove instead!

Comment: This style is not good, because you're killing other 'mousemove' event handlers.
It's better to attach an event handler instead.